# mechanize doesn't want to enable cookie

Tags: python, cookies, mechanize

I tried to login into my Microsoft account, but it doesn't workL

```
br.open(https://login.live.com/)
```

The response contains something like this:

> Please enable cookies in your browser

`cookiejar` doesn't help.

I tried to do this:

```
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
```

But it failed every time. How do I log into my Microsoft account with `mechanize`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the cookie jar as follows:

```
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
```